# Handling multi table transaction in cassandra

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

I have two table:

```
posts : {post_id, text}
```

This will store all post by its id. Another table that stores the count of likes, comments of each post:

```
counts: {post_id, likes, comments}
```

i have another table that map users who has already liked a post so that by checking the entry here we may/may not allow to like again

```
post_like_user: {post_is, user_id}
```

last one is comment table for each post:

```
comments: {post_id, comment_id, comment_text, }
```

So the use cases are:

1. If a user make any comment in `comments` tale increment the `comments` count in `counts` table.
2. If a use likes a post check first `post_like_user` table if the entry doesn't exist then increment the `likes` count in `counts` table insert the user id in `post_like_user` table.

Does these kind of use case are handle by cassandra/mongodb in production? How can i implement these use cases in cassandra/mongodb as it doesn't support ACID ?

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra has a concept of batches, which is quite similar to transactions (at least from description). Link to documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html

So basically what you'd do:

```
BEGIN LOGGED BATCH
// do your dml
APPLY BATCH;
```

Comment: from the doc `Writing to several partitions might require interaction with several nodes in the cluster, causing a great deal of latency for the write operation.` SO if you do write on different table then performnace might be low

Comment: Well, yes. But that's a limitation of distributed databases. Even if you implement it yourself, this is going to be a bummer. Cassandra team has given an option to batch inserts to multiple partitions, so why not to use it?

Answer (score 0):

> If a use likes a post check first post_like_user table if the entry doesn't exist then increment the likes count in counts table insert the user id in post_like_user table.

There are possible issues with this case:

1. Race condition. 'Check and update' will be not performed as an atomic operation. In Cassandra there is no way to provide atomicity for between several tables and several operations.
2. Inconsistent data in `post_like_user` table between replicas or you will have to provide strong consistency which will cost you some performance.

It will be better to avoid 'check and update' behavior: do not use separate table for counter and use `count()` function to get number of likes by post:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post_like_user where post_id='post id';
```

This request should work pretty fast because it will performed within one partition (if post_id is partition key)

Another way is use separate `counts` table, but update it in a background process, which will periodically request 'likes' count from `post_like_user` table by `count(*)` function and put the count into `counts` table.

Comment: considering a huge number of column `count(*)` will be poor performer

Comment: Normally you want to have a separate table for counts and use `counter` datatype for it. Recommended by DataStax.

Comment: Batches should be applied to updates for one table and one partition and they designed for improving performance. Use batches with different tables is wrong

Comment: @irisha_murrr There is nothing about batches  in my answer

Comment: My fault, I believe I wanted to post it for the answer above